# Редирект в nginx всей папке, кроме корня

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Задача: Сделать редирект со всех страниц site.com/en/(*) редирект на site.com/en/
Я написал правило, но оно также включает сам индеркс адреса site.com/en/ и получится бесконечный редирект.

```
location  ~ ^/en/(.*)$ {
        return 301 https://site.com/en/;
    }
```

А как добавить исключение адреса https://site.com/en/?
Может что-то такое?

```
location  ~ ^/en/(.*)$ {
      if ($request_uri !~ ^/en/) {
        return 301 https://site.com/en/;
      }
}
```

Comment: Замените `.*` на `.+` может?

Comment: Не сработало. Зацикленный редирект получил. –

Answer (score 1):

```
location  ~ ^/en/(.+)$ {
        return 301 https://site.com/en/;
}
```

.+ означает, что после /en/ обязательно должно быть что-то еще. В этом случае вы не получите циклического редиректа

Comment: Не сработало. Зацикленный редирект получил.

Comment: в браузере в терминале разработчика (F-12) на закладке Network усть возможно получить информацию о заголовках запроса и ответа. Интересует заголовок ответа Location. Что в нем при первом запросе ?

Comment: Во всех пишет так
location: http://site.com/en/

Сайта под HTTPS и стоит авторедирект с HTTP на HTTPS.

Comment: вот вы сами нашли ответ, что не работает не мой локейшн, а другие настройки вашего вебсервера. Устраните проблему с редиректами http / https или задайте новый запрос